# Fatal error<: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos

Me tira el siguiente error al momento de querer consultar un Ticket que ya tengo en mi base de datos
Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\HelpDesk\models\Ticket.php:38
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\HelpDesk\models\Ticket.php(38): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\HelpDesk\controller\ticket.php(12): Ticket->listar_ticket_x_usu('1')
#2 {main}
thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\HelpDesk\models\Ticket.php on line 38/>

Mi codigo es

***controller.php***

```
<?php
    require_once("../config/conexion.php");
    require_once("../models/Ticket.php");
    $ticket = new Ticket();

    switch($_GET["op"]){
        case "insert":
            $ticket->insert_ticket($_POST["usu_id"],$_POST["cat_id"],$_POST["tick_titulo"],$_POST["tick_descrip"]);
        break;

        case "listar_x_usu":
            $datos=$ticket->listar_ticket_x_usu($_POST["usu_id"]);
            $data= Array();
            foreach($datos as $row){
                $sub_array = array();
                $sub_array[] = $row["tick_id"];
                $sub_array[] = $row["cat_nom"];
                $sub_array[] = $row["tick_titulo"];
                $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" onClick="ver('.$row["tick_id"].');"  id="'.$row["tick_id"].'" class="btn btn-inline btn-primary btn-sm ladda-button"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></button>';
                $data[] = $sub_array;
            }

            $results = array(
                "sEcho"=>1,
                "iTotalRecords"=>count($data),
                "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>count($data),
                "aaData"=>$data);
            echo json_encode($results);
        break;
    }
?>

models/ticket.php

<?php
    class Ticket extends Conectar{

        public function insert_ticket($usu_id,$cat_id,$tick_titulo,$tick_descrip){
            $conectar= parent::conexion();
            parent::set_names();
            $sql="INSERT INTO tm_ticket (tick_id,usu_id,cat_id,tick_titulo,tick_descrip, est) VALUES (NULL,?,?, ?,?,'1');";
            $sql=$conectar->prepare($sql);
            $sql->bindValue(1, $usu_id);
            $sql->bindValue(2, $cat_id);
            $sql->bindValue(3, $tick_titulo);
            $sql->bindValue(4, $tick_descrip);
            $sql->execute();
            return $resultado=$sql->fetchAll();
        }

        public function listar_ticket_x_usu($usu_id){
            $conectar= parent::conexion();
            parent::set_names();
            $sql="SELECT 
                tm_ticket.tick_id,
                tm_ticket.usu_id,
                tm_ticket.cat_id,
                tm_ticket.tick_titulo,
                tm_ticket.tick_descrip,
                tm_usuario.usu_nom,
                tm_usuario.usu_ape,
                tm_categoria.cat_nom
                FROM 
                tm_ticket
                INNER join tm_categoria on tm_ticket.cat_id = tm_categoria.cat_id
                INNER join tm_usuario on tm_ticket.usu_id = tm_usuario.usu_id
                WHERE
                tm_ticket.est = 1
                AND tm_usuario.usu_id=1";
            $sql=$conectar->prepare($sql);
            $sql->bindValue(1, $usu_id);
            $sql->execute();
            return $resultado=$sql->fetchAll();
        }

    }
?>

Muchas gracias!
```

Comment: Buenas, Pablo, en tu consulta para listar tickets se te ha pasado poner una ? como placeholder para cuando hagas el bind con el id del usuario.

Comment: Como bien dice @RubioRic te falta poner un marcador en la consulta del `SELECT`. Otra cosa que veo es que mareas demasiado los datos. Ya `fetchAll()` te devuelve un array con los datos, ¿por qué al recibirlos los lees de nuevo y los metes en otro array? Me refiero a esta parte: `foreach($datos as $row) { $sub_array = array(); $sub_array[] = $row["tick_id"]; //... }` En ese contexto ya **`$datos`** tiene todos los valores que ahora metes en `$sub_array` para luego meter en otro array llamado `$data`. Lo único nuevo ahí es el `button`, pero eso lo puedes hacer en el cliente ...